# .net Regular Expression with C#

Tags: c#-3.0

I need to find the Registration number i.e. 000010884409 in below string multiple time with help of regular expression in a for loop with C# and save it in a list. Can any one help me on this?

string var = GetRegistrationNumber('000010884409');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_4360a1ad_8180");express('000000012345')

Comment: Deleted my answer as I was incorrect. I will post a new one once I've validated my results.

Comment: Answer is undeleted, with the correct answer, input sample, and output. Tested using **Expresso**

Answer (score 0):

The following Regular Expression:

`GetRegistrationNumber\('([\d]+)'\)`

Ran on:

```
string var = GetRegistrationNumber('000010884409');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_4360a1ad_8180");express('000000012345')
string var = GetRegistrationNumber('000010884408');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_4360a1ad_8180");express('000000012345')
string var = GetRegistrationNumber('000010884407');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_4360a1ad_8180");express('000000012345')
string var = GetRegistrationNumber('000010884406');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_4360a1ad_8180");express('000000012345')
string var = GetRegistrationNumber('000010884405');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_4360a1ad_8180");express('000000012345')
string var = GetRegistrationNumber('000010884404');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_4360a1ad_8180");express('000000012345')
```

Produces the following matches:

- GetRegistrationNumber('000010884409')

  - Capture Group 1: 000010884409
- GetRegistrationNumber('000010884408')

  - Capture Group 1: 000010884408
- GetRegistrationNumber('000010884407')

  - Capture Group 1: 000010884407
- GetRegistrationNumber('000010884406')

  - Capture Group 1: 000010884406
- GetRegistrationNumber('000010884405')

  - Capture Group 1: 000010884405
- GetRegistrationNumber('000010884404')

  - Capture Group 1: 000010884404

Comment: I need to have only number out of this not as group..I just need to have 000010884409

Comment: @Man: The *Capture GROUP* #1 will have just the number, the Match has the whole thing. So just navigate to the group inside the match. There's no other way to differentiate it from another number.